# Sequelize, how to use Op.contains to find models that have certain values

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on some project about renting houses and appartments and I've reached the point when i need to implement filtering houses based on features they have(wifi, security and other staff). In the beginning I decided to try Sequelize ORM for the first time. Stuff like adding, creating, editing is working fine, but the filtering part is where I have some problems.

I'm working with nodejs,express and postgresql. 
I need to find all houses that have features listed in the array of features IDs. Here is what I've tried. In this example I'm trying to get houses which have features with ids 1, 2 and 4.

```
db.House.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.HouseFeature, 
    as: 'HouseFeatures',
    where: {
      featureId: {
        [Op.contains]: [1, 2, 4] //<- array of featuresIds
      }  
    }
  }]
})
```

Fetching houses by single feature id works fine because i don't use Op.contains there.
Here are some relations related to this case:

```
House.hasMany(models.HouseFeature, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
HouseFeature.belongsTo(models.House);
```

HouseFeature contains featureId field.
Here is the error I get:

```
error: оператор не существует: integer @> unknown
       at Connection.parseE (C:\***\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:601:11)
       at Connection.parseMessage (C:\***\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:398:19)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\***\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:120:22)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
     name: 'error',
     length: 397,
     severity: 'ОШИБКА',
     code: '42883',
     detail: undefined,
     hint:
      'Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.',
     position: '851',
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file:
      'd:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\parser\\parse_oper.c',
     line: '731',
     routine: 'op_error',
     sql:
      'SELECT "House"."id", "House"."title", "House"."description", "House"."price", "House"."address", "House"."lat", "House"."lon", "House"."kitchen", "House"."bathrooms", "House"."floor", "House"."totalFloors", "House"."people", "House"."area", "House"."bedrooms", "House"."trusted", "House"."createdAt", "House"."updatedAt", "House"."CityId", "House"."ComplexId", "House"."OwnerProfileId", "House"."HouseTypeId", "House"."RentTypeId", "HouseFeatures"."id" AS "HouseFeatures.id", "HouseFeatures"."featureId" AS "HouseFeatures.featureId", "HouseFeatures"."createdAt" AS "HouseFeatures.createdAt", "HouseFeatures"."updatedAt" AS "HouseFeatures.updatedAt", "HouseFeatures"."HouseId" AS "HouseFeatures.HouseId" FROM "Houses" AS "House" INNER JOIN "HouseFeatures" AS "HouseFeatures" ON "House"."id" = "HouseFeatures"."HouseId" AND "HouseFeatures"."featureId" @> \'1,2\';'
```

Sorry for some russian there.

UPDATE:

I've managed to do what i needed by changing each House relating only to one HouseFeature, and by changing that HouseFeature model to store array of featureIds. Op.contains works fine.

```
  db.House.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: db.HouseFeature, 
        as: 'HouseFeature',
        where: {
          features: {
            [Op.contains]: req.body.features
          }  
        },
      }]     
  })
  // Associations
  HouseFeature.belongsTo(models.House);
  House.hasOne(models.HouseFeature, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });

  const HouseFeature = sequelize.define('HouseFeature', {
    features: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER)
    }
  }, {});
```

Now i have one little issue. Can I somehow link HouseFeature model with Feature model to fetch feature icon images and name later on? With Feature ids being stored inside HouseFeature array.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to get houses including id (one of array) ?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `Op.in` operator instead of `Op.contains`?

Comment: Op.contains appears to be for Postgres array types... but your model appears to be 1:M.... so maybe @Ihor is right?  Are you looking for houses that have ALL of those features?  Or, houses that have at least one of those features?

Comment: The idea is user can create house and set features in it. And other users can filter houses depending on features. For example users can find houses with wifi, balcony and parking features. I need my query to return houses with selected features.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the difference between `Op.in` and `Op.contains`:

> `[Op.in]: [1, 2],           // IN [1, 2]`
>
> `[Op.contains]: [1, 2]      // @> [1, 2] (PG array contains operator)`

It looks like `HouseFeatures.featureId` is a PK with type `integer`, not a `postgres array`.

Please try:

```
db.House.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.HouseFeature, 
    as: 'HouseFeatures',
    where: {
      featureId: {
        [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3]
      }  
    }
  }]
})
```

or even

```
db.House.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.HouseFeature, 
    as: 'HouseFeatures',
    where: {
      featureId: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  }]
})
```

instead

Comment: Seems like you are right. HouseFeatures.featureId is integer. But I've already tried Op.in, and I had a problem with it - It returned same House multiple times if House had more than one feature. For example if I asked for Houses with 3 features, Op.in returned same house 3 times.

Comment: Works fine for me - returns arrays of unique Houses with a list of HouseFeatures  

https://codeshare.io/adyqV4